# Warning: setState(...) on ComponentDidMount when navigating using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component called `Containers` which have a list components called `ContainerStatus`.

When I try to navigate to my component using `<Link>` of **react-router** I got this warning in my component child:

"***Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.***".

But if I use direct link (`localhost:3000/containers`) to my component, the warning does not trigger.

**router:**

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
  <Route path='/containers' component={Containers} />
</Route>
```

**Containers**

```
renderData () {
  return (
    <table className={'table table-hover'}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <Header>ID</Header>
          <Header>Name</Header>
          <Header>IMAGE</Header>
          <Header>Server</Header>
          <Header>Actions</Header>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {
          this.props.containers.map((e, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{e.id}</td>
              <td>{e.containerName}</td>
              <td>{e.image}</td>
              <td>{e.server.name}</td>
              <td>
                <ContainerStatus id={e.containerName} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledLink to='container' style='btn btn-primary'>Create</StyledLink>
      {this.props.isFetching ? <Loader /> : this.renderData()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ContainerStatus**

```
class ContainerStatus extends Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = { container: {} }
    this.fetchContainer = this.fetchContainer.bind(this)
  }

  getRow (element) {
    return element.map((a, index) => <td key={index}>{a}</td>);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchContainer()
  }

  fetchContainer () {
    axios.get('api/containersApp/' + this.props.id)
      .then(response => { this.setState({ container: response.data }); })
      .catch((error) => { this.setState({ container: 'blabla' }); });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* do things */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I presume the problem is when you navigate to a different page right after your `ContainerStatus` has mounted. The API call is triggered in `componentDidMount` and once it completes and if you have already navigated to another page, current code attempts to `setState` on an unmounted component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are navigating to different page in between the ajax call. Better abort the ajax call on

> componentWillUnmount

method. Aborting the ajax call will prevent this warning.